Command to fold all "properties" drawers in file
I’m looking for an interactive command that would fold / unfold all the :PROPERTIES: drawers in an org file.
I’m sure this command must exist, I just can’t find it – and I’m curious to how you did find it, if you do!

org-fold-hide-drawer-all will hide all drawers in the buffer (or with an active region, all drawers in the region).
I found it by doing C-h f org-fold--drawer TAB and then doing C-h f <function name> on each of the likely candidates (there were only three of them).
EDIT: My apologies: org-fold-hide-drawer-all was made interactive with commit 13353f1fa34f6f085ffbf142b380af7308f02981 but that change has not been incorporated into the stable releases yet.
In 9.6.151, you'll have to override the function with a copy of the function from the commit above. Add the following to your init file:
(with-eval-after-load 'org-fold
  (defun org-fold-hide-drawer-all (&optional begin end)
    "Fold all drawers in the current buffer or active region BEGIN..END."
    (interactive (list (and (use-region-p) (region-beginning))
                       (and (use-region-p) (region-end))))
    (let ((begin (or begin (point-min)))
          (end (or end (point-max))))
      (org-fold--hide-drawers begin end))))


[1] Actually, in any stable 9.6.x release. The change will probably not be included in any of the 9.6.x series releases: I suspect it will be included in 9.7 and later.

Thank you for your answer! org-fold-hide-drawer is not an interactive function, is it? I can’t seem to use it with M-x (which is the point).
When I do C-h f org-fold--drawer TAB, I have absolutely no suggestion on my Emacs. For reference, I’m on Emacs 29.3 with org-version 9.6.15.

You got the name of the function wrong: org-fold-hide-drawer-all is an interactive function (AKA command), so you can call it with M-x.

Are you using standard completion or some third-party completion package? When I do C-h f org-fold-drawer TAB I get a completion buffer with four possibilities (one of which is org-fold-hide-drawer-all.

See the edited answer: no stable release contains the interactive version of org-fold-hide-drawer-all yet. I provide a workaround in the answer.

Thank you for your answer update and your comments! It works well for folding all properties on a buffer, despite it being slow.  But what about unfolding?

Yes, I noticed the slowness too, but I have not investigated yet.I don't think there is a corresponding unfolding function, but it is not too difficult to write your own. But you probably should ask it in a different question.
